# rmagick preventing rails server from working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I have to use rmagick, and it is not allowing me to start the rails server. I have read around on here and Google, none of the solutions have help so far. There is something going wrong with the Library and I'm not sure how to fix it.

If anyone has advice with fixing this exact problem that would be much appreciated.

```
/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/rmagick.rb:11:in `require': dlopen(/Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/rmagick.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /Users/lexi87/dating/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to fix this error, so this should work for anyone else if they're having the same exact problem.

Here are the steps to fixing:

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
gem uninstall rmagick
sudo gem install json # (not sure this step is needed)
sudo apt-get install libmagick9-dev
bundle install
```

And then it work perfect. Now I can launch rails server and I receive no more errors. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: You shouldn't have to uninstall `imagemagick`, just reinstall `rmagick` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Wait... you have a `brew` and then an `apt-get`... which system is this supposed to work on?!

Comment: I had the same problem. My fix was to brew uninstall imagemagick; brew install imagemagick; gem uninstall rmagick; bundle install.

Comment: and I wouldn't run `gem install` as super-user. This can result in super-annoying setups.

Answer (score 8):

You just need reinstall rmagick with your current imagemagick

```
gem install rmagick
```

In someother issues i found the following fixed the issue by using,

```
gem pristine rmagick
```

Comment: I've done that and it still shows the same error. I also get a few "unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8" errors too for gem install rmagick.

Comment: What about the second one? otherwise just uninstall the rmagick gems and install again and try it.. Because that's solved my problem.

Comment: Same. It did the pristine action fine. Just still provides the error for rails server.

Comment: Same error posted in the original posting.   Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-Q16.7.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick2.bundle

Comment: did you run bundle install?

Answer (score 3):

I had several problems with my install, what worked for me was

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
gem uninstall rmagick
brew install imagemagick
bundle install
brew unlink libtool 
brew link libtool
```

without the first I was getting errors trying to install rmagick and without the last two there were errors starting the rails server

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue.  I had tried a lot of different tricks, and oddly enough what worked was this oddness.  The first 2 commands seem useless, but considering I don't know how this worked, I'm leaving them in, too.

**Don't ask questions, just run them and embrace the rmagick**

```
brew install libtool --universal
brew link libtool
brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool
gem uninstall rmagick
gem install rmagick
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate your answers. You can either answer each question specifically focusing on the bits that differ, or flag the questions as duplicates and answer just once.